# Replace("\"", "\\\"") gets the value \\\" instead of \\"

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
string a = "\"";
string b = a.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

I want the b be instantiated with the  `\\"` value. Instead, when the replace is performed, the b has the `\\\"` value.

Why this is happening? Is anyway that replace the `\"` value and get the `\\"` instead of the `\\\"` value?

Thank you

Comment: it probably is... sure that what you're seeing is not the visual studio debugger insight/data tip, which is also showing the escaped version?

Comment: How are you inspecting the value of `b`?  Also, there is probably a more suitable way of escaping your strings than whatever you're trying to do here.

Comment: You'll be getting escaped backslashes.

Comment: You are looking at the string in the debugger. Print it to see that the first two slashes are not there.

Comment: The value is `\"`, [Click on the loop](http://imgur.com/a/9ab5S), to see the "real" value. you need to escape each `\` and the `"` with a `\ ` , result  `\\\\\"`

Comment: That's going to replace a single double quote with a single backslash followed by a single double quote.  The debugger view would escape both with an extra backslash, so with escapes it would be `\\\"` and without `\"`, but never `\\"`.  Do you really want two backslashes?  If so you want to replace it with `\\\\\"`

Comment: Please see: [here Literals section](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx)

Comment: @dlatikay Yes, so stupid. You're right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the @dlatikay said on the comments, because I'm **seeing** the values **on** the visual studio **debbuger**, the debugger escapes again the string transforming the `\\"` value into `\\\"` value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add 2 more slashes if you want to initialize it with `\\"`

Your existing code replaces it with `\\\"`. That means one `\\` is calculated as one back-slash, and `\"` is escaped double-quote. So, b becomes `\"`.

If you use `\\\\\"`. You get 2 back-slashes and one double quote.

```
    string a = "\"";
   string b = a.Replace("\"", "\\\\\"");
```